# I need to add a checkbox and a add more images (+ icon) through which I can proceed with adding screenshots in flutter which has progress bar in it

Tags: image, flutter, plugins

[enter image description here][1]I need to add a progress bar indicator in my app.
Which package should I choose ? How should I proceed ?

Goals I want to achieve in this tasks are:

1. I need to upload an Image to the server where I have to indicate the progress bar.
2. I need to add a check box that gets a tick in it as soon as I add an image.
3. I need to have a + icon from where I can add more images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the LinearProgressIndicator which is a Widget from the SDK.

You could either display an 'infinite' progress bar with the following method

```
Center(
  child: LinearProgressIndicator(),
)
```

or a Determinate progress bar, updated by retrieving how much of the picture you uploaded.

```
Center(
  child: LinearProgressIndicator(
    value: _percentageOfImageUploaded,
  )
)
```

where `_percentageOfImageUploaded` is a value between 0.0 and 1.0.
To update this value, you have plenty of solutions (Provider, Stream, setState...) depending on your current implementation